# How to check linear independence

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, independence

How can I check the linear independence of my variables?

I have this system $Ax=b$ where A is a $N\times 4$ matrix.

I want to check the linear independence between the 4 variables in matrix $A$.

Comment: Do you need to do this by hand or using statistical computing software? Here's a post on the mathematics page that may point you in the right direction: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228971/whats-the-relationship-between-singular-nontrivial-and-linear-dependent-basic.

Comment: I am using computing software. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the rank of matrix A is 4.
Equivalently, consider the equation A*[x1 x2 x3 x4]'=0 where [x1 x2 x3 x4] is the vector. Apply Gaussian elimination to see whether one of the 4 xi can be arbitrarily chosen.